# sum consecutive values in the same group ordered by date

Tags: r

I am trying to sum consecutive values that have the same student_id and are ordered by date.

I have tried using sequence(rle()) but the order by dates is not working.

```
row student_id  date        pass/fail  streak
1   2           2019-05-24  0          0
2   2           2019-05-25  -1         -1
3   1           2019-05-24  1          2
4   1           2019-05-28  -1         -1
5   2           2019-05-23  1          1
6   1           2019-05-27  1          3
7   2           2019-05-28  -1         -2
8   1           2019-05-23  1          1
```

The streak column is the desired output, and the dates are not in order in the original data frame which I think is what is the problem.

Comment: Why is answer to fourth row not two?

Comment: I would like the count to start over after every sign change

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Using the ordering indexes `o`, order the original data frame by `student_id` and `date`.  Now, apply `cumsum` by `student_id` and `pass/fail` to `pass/fail` and finally revert to the original order.

```
library(data.table)

o <- with(DF, order(student_id, date))

transform(DF[o, ], 
  streak = ave(`pass/fail`, rleid(student_id, `pass/fail`), FUN = cumsum))[order(o), ]
```

giving:

```
  ow student_id       date pass.fail streak
1  1          2 2019-05-24         0      0
2  2          2 2019-05-25        -1     -1
3  3          1 2019-05-24         1      2
4  4          1 2019-05-28        -1     -1
5  5          2 2019-05-23         1      1
6  6          1 2019-05-27         1      3
7  7          2 2019-05-28        -1     -2
8  8          1 2019-05-23         1      1
```

### Note

The input in reproducible form:

```
    Lines <- "ow student_id  date        pass/fail  streak
1   2           2019-05-24  0          0
2   2           2019-05-25  -1         -1
3   1           2019-05-24  1          2
4   1           2019-05-28  -1         -1
5   2           2019-05-23  1          1
6   1           2019-05-27  1          3
7   2           2019-05-28  -1         -2
8   1           2019-05-23  1          1"
DF <- read.table(text = Lines,  header = TRUE, check.names = FALSE)
DF$date <- as.Date(DF$date)
DF$streak <- NULL
```

Comment: how do you get the order to stay? I just had them ordered to show the desired output. thanks

Comment: I am still having trouble getting the initial data frame ordered to be able to run the transform.  I put it in the desired order to show what the output should be, but the student_id and date are not in order currently

Comment: edited- the rows are out of order originally which is the problem

Comment: OK. Have revised answer accordingly.